# C#: Controllers in a re-usable library with the .net core framework

Tags: c#, controller

I've written all the classes and controllers for a web api to interact with a very large database (dozens of tables and controllers). I need to write a lot of small apps for specific tasks, as such, it would be idea if the controllers could also be a library file.

I've seen some old tutorials that suggest this is possible, but they no longer seem to work.

Could anyone please point me to somewhere that explains how this can be achieved; or, if there's a better best practices approach I should be taking.

Have all the object classes in their own library, and a working web app that interacts with the database. Want to extra the controllers into a library or include them in the existing object classes library.

Comment: At this point, it seem the answer might be within Repository Patterns, Units of Work, and Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

By placing controllers in the library, do you mean having generic controllers so you can reuse them whenever you want for whatever model you need? Of so, you can check my library https://github.com/Ryukote/CoreGenerics which is also available on Nuget so you can add it to your project and use it as is.

Comment: Generic controllers might be a good way to reduce code bloat in general, but I want the object classes and controllers that relate to them in a separate library, that can be used by any app I write. In theory, should work, since controllers are just methods. I'm guessing it's something to do with inheriting from the BaseController class or using an interface.